# Error when using command as parameter for an other command

Tags: macros, arguments

I want to use 2 seperate commands to first execute a calculation on a number and then displaying the number with plus or minus using following code.

When trying to run it I get various errors. I think that propably `\FPeval` is causing problems.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\MyHalf[1]{\FPeval\result{trunc(#1 / 2, 0)}\result}

\newcommand\MyDisplaySign[1]{\ifthenelse{#1<0}{$#1$}{$+#1$}}

\begin{document}

\MyHalf{12}

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{12}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\FPeval` is not expandable, it _assigns_ the result to `\result`, so you need to do the evaluation first and then pass `\result` to the expansion context in the numeric test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that for the `\ifthenelse` test compare `#1<0`, `#1` has to be a number. But if you pass a macro that contains a number (or, in some way, expands to a number), that macro has to be expandable, so that `\ifthenelse` can performing the test. The problem, as David said in the comment, is that `\FPeval` is not expandable because it assigns the result to `\result`.

But `\fp_eval:n` is expandable :)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\MyHalf
  { m }
  {
    \fp_eval:n { trunc ( #1 / 2, 0 ) }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\MyDisplaySign
  { m }
  {
    \int_compare:nTF
    { #1 <= \c_zero_int }
    { $   #1 $ }
    { $ + #1 $ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MyHalf{12} % Prints 6

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{12}} % Prints +6

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{-12}} % Prints -6

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{0}} % Doesn't print "+0" because 0 isn't larger than \c_zero_int, so the conditional evaluates to true

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{-0}} % Prints -0 because of the leading sign

\end{document}
```

The only issue is with `0`. With the code above you don't get the leading `+` sign because `0=0` is true, so the first (for negative numbers) is taken. If you want the leading `+` sign then you have to print the sign if the value is equal to zero too, but then with negative zero you get `+-0`, because `-0=+0` and the sign is added too:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\MyHalf
  { m }
  {
    \fp_eval:n { trunc ( #1 / 2, 0 ) }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\MyDisplaySign
  { m }
  {
    \int_compare:nTF
    { #1 >= \c_zero_int }
    { $ + #1 $ }
    { $   #1 $ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MyHalf{12} % Prints 6

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{12}} % Prints +6

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{-12}} % Prints -6

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{0}} % Prints +0

\MyDisplaySign{\MyHalf{-0}} % Prints +-0

\end{document}
```

The isn't, as far as I know, a way to get `-0` and `+0` correct without doing extra tests for this specific scenario.

Comment: `ifthenelse` _does_ expand the argument in the test, the problem is rather that `\FPeval` is not expandable. (but using fp_eval is better, I agree:-)

Comment: This would print `+0` With `\int_compare:nTF { #1 <= 0 }` you'd solve the issue. Or reverse the test: `\int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } > { 0 } { $+#1$ } { $#1$ }`

Comment: The changed version still prints +0.

Comment: @egreg The second one. The first one prints `6, +6, −6, 0, −0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\MyHalf[1]{\FPeval\result{trunc(#1 / 2, 0)}}

\newcommand\MyDisplaySign[1]{\ifthenelse{#1<0}{$#1$}{$+#1$}}

\begin{document}

\MyHalf{12}%
% Now the result is stored in the macro \result.
% Let's see the result:
\result

% Now let's see the result with preceding algebraic sign:
\MyDisplaySign{\result}

\end{document}
```